# Load and use Codeigniter model in non Codeigniter class

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpunit

I was just wondering if there is a way to use codeigniter model in other non Codeigniter classes... Let me give you an example.

I have this MyTestClassTests class which extends PHPUNIT_Framework_testCase

```
<?php        
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCapabilityType;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Interactions\WebDriverActions;
use Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser;

class MyTestClassTests extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testDoSomething()
    {
       // Do some test
       // get results
       // Store results via Codeigniter Model, if possible?
       $results = 'some results';
       $this->load->model('results');
       $this->results->import($results);
    }
}
```

Now once test is finished i would like to store test results in to the database. Is there a way to call/initialize CodeIgniter model in current class to use it and store data? This file is located in the Codeigniters controllers folder.

If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you appear to be unit testing you should consider using [ci_phpunit-test](https://kenjis.github.io/ci-phpunit-test/) which makes it much easier to use PHPUnit with CodeIgniter 3.x.

Because you're unit testing the following may not apply. These examples only work within an fully instantiated CI framework. Within that context there are a couple ways to give a stand-alone class access to the CI object.

One approach is to capture the CI instance in a class property.

```
class MyTestClassTests extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Assign the CodeIgniter super-object
        $this->CI = & get_instance();
    }

    public function testDoSomething()
    {
       // Do some test
       // get results
       // Store results via Codeigniter Model, if possible?
       $results = 'some results';
       //use the class property to access CI classes and methods
       $this->CI->load->model('results');
       $this->CI->results->import($results);
    }
}
```

A second approach uses the PHP magic method `__get`. The advantage is it's much easier to write the code. The disadvantage is it's a tiny bit less efficient because extra code is executed each time you access the CI instance.

```
class MyTestClassTests extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * Enables the use of CI super-global without having to define an extra variable.
     *
     * @param   $var The CI property or method to access
     * @return  mixed
     */
    public function __get($var)
    {
        return get_instance()->$var;
    }

    public function testDoSomething()
    {
       // Do some test
       // get results
       // Store results via Codeigniter Model, if possible?
       $results = 'some results';
       //you get to write code as if you were part of the CI object.
       //IOW, you write code normally
       $this->load->model('results');
       $this->results->import($results);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

In order to use codeigniter model in your non codeigniter class you have to instantiate CI first.

In your case below code will work.

```
$CI = & get_instance()
$CI->load->model('results');
$CI->results->your_function();
```

Comment: can you please provide an example on my case, please!?

Comment: i probably have to include some files? index.php?